# Robospice using caching in a dynamic ormlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, caching, robospice

I have an android app that loads data from a server and displays it in an endless scroll in a recyclerview.

It loads 5 items per page and if you scroll down, it triggers another 5 page to load.

Each time I scroll down, robospice is triggered and the 5 items will be cached using the current page number as the cacheKey into a SQLite database through ORMlite. The array of items returned by my server will then be added onto the total list of all items which I saved in an arraylist. This total list is then passed to my recyclerview adapter, which updates the recyclerview.

**Therefore:**

(cacheKey/page number:1) - first 5 items

(cacheKey/page number:2) - next 5 items

(cacheKey/page number:3) - next 5 items

Now I can also delete items on my android app. So therefore, if I don't like item 4 on page 2 for example, I can swipe left and delete it.

Since I don't keep track of the pages in my arraylist (it is a total list of everything), I can't really go:

1. spiceManager.getFromCache() - fetches the items from cache but since I don't keep track of the page in which the item was loaded from (remember, I load from the total arraylist), I do not have the cache key. I can't tell if the 9th item was loaded from the 2 page, for example, and therefore I don't have the cache key to fetch it from the cache.
2. spiceManager.removeDataFromCache() - delete the data and the associated cacheKey for those 5 items but save the 5 items temporarily into a arraylist.
3. spiceManager.putInCache() - I would delete the item in the temporary arraylist and then put the data from the arraylist back into cache with the same cacheKey for the  4 items as 1 is now removed

What I can do however is this:

1. spiceManager.removeAllDataFromCache() - remove all the data from the cache / SQLite DB.
2. spiceManager.putInCache() - put into cache all the data excluding the item that was previously deleted and issuing out a new cache key.

What I'm worried about with this method however, is that it is highly resource intensive. Each time you delete something, the whole DB is deleted and resaved without the deleted item.

I think that if I want to add a new item dynamically to my SQLite DB, this issue would also come about so I would also have to delete the whole DB and re-add it the whole arraylist into my SQLite and then re-issue a cacheKey.

Are there any other strategies out there for what I want to do when I want to make changes to my SQLite cache?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not cache everything together in a single list/table? The `RecyclerView.Adapter` doesn't care which page your items are coming from, in general.

Comment: I can't really because through using the endless scrollview, I'm calling my REST API each time I scroll. 5 additional items load through Robospice each time I scroll and is added to the cache with a cachekey in ormlite. I don't load the entire list of 1000 items at one go as that would take forever. If I did that, I could definitely cache everything together using one cachekey.

Comment: My idea was to pass the list appended with the last X (5, in your case) items to the previous result as RoboSpice result (thus making it automatically cached). So, maintain the last result in memory (essentially `RecyclerView.Adapter`'s list of items), append the newest result from network, return the whole thing as a result from RoboSpice request or cache it manually by using a single cache key (not including the page number). I have used a similar approach successfully, but it would take me a bit longer to extract the important parts from there.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. But in that case, you will have 1 - 5 cached under key1. Then 1 - 10 under key2. The last key would have the longest and complete list. Since each time you cache, robospice writes it to the ormlite db, you would also constantly have to delete the older keys (key1 key 2 etc) and only keep the latest cachekey as the latest cachekey would be the complete list and this would keep the db in a reasonable size. Would this also not be inefficient as you are constantly deleting older cache?

Comment: One remark, I was using file system cache, not ORMLite. With hundreds of items (scrolling until you get bored :), there was no visible performance decrease. But in general, yes, only way to prevent your concern is to implement a custom `CacheManager` and/or `ObjectPersister` in RoboSpice and handle it more gracefully than  that.

Comment: Is there anyway to use Robospice just to cache all network requests without a cachekey? I can easily just use the DAO in ormlite to query or delete or add to the underlying database instead of managing this through cachekeys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82600/discussion-between-simon-and-nekojsi).